# Linking problems C++, glew, and SDL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, sdl

I'm having some linker errors and I can't really decipher what they mean so I'd appreciate some help. I'm trying to write a simple program that just create's a basic fragment shader and a basic vertex shader. here's the code:

**Shader.h**~

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <glew.h>


class Shader
{
    public:
    const static unsigned int NUMOFSHADERS = 2;

    GLuint m_program;
    GLuint m_shaders[NUMOFSHADERS];

    void Bind();
    static std::string LoadShader(const std::string& filename);
    static GLuint CreateShader(const std::string& text, GLenum shadertype);
    Shader(const std::string& filename);
    virtual ~Shader();
};
```

**Shader.cpp**~

```
#include "Shader.h"


Shader::Shader(const std::string& filename)
{
    m_program = glCreateProgram();
    m_shaders[0] = CreateShader(LoadShader(filename + ".shade_v"),     GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    m_shaders[1] = CreateShader(LoadShader(filename + ".shade_f"),     GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; NUMOFSHADERS; i++)
    {
        glAttachShader(m_program, m_shaders[i]);
    };

    glBindAttribLocation(m_program, 0, "position");
    glLinkProgram(m_program);
}

Shader::~Shader()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; NUMOFSHADERS; i++)
    {
        glDetachShader(m_program, m_shaders[i]);
        glDeleteShader(m_shaders[i]);
    }

    glDeleteProgram(m_program);
}

static std::string LoadShader(const std::string& filename)
{

    std::ifstream file;
    std::string output;
    std::string line;
    file.open(filename.c_str());
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while (file)
        {
            std::getline(file, line);
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
        file.close();
        return output;
    }
}

static GLuint CreateShader(const std::string& text, GLenum shadertype)
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shadertype);
    const GLchar* shadersourcestrings[1];
    GLint shadersourcelengths[1];

    shadersourcestrings[0] = text.c_str();
    shadersourcelengths[0] = text.length();

    glShaderSource(shader, 1, shadersourcestrings, shadersourcelengths);
    glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
}

void Shader::Bind()
{
    glUseProgram(m_program);
}
```

**Display.h**~

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL.h>
#include <glew.h>
#include <iostream>

class Display
{
public:
    void Update();
    void Clear(float r, float g, float b, float a);
    bool isClosed();
    Display(int width, int height, const char *title);
    virtual  ~Display();
private:
    bool m_isClosed;
    SDL_Window* m_window;
    SDL_GLContext m_context;
};
```

**Display.cpp**~

```
#pragma once
#include "Display.h"

Display::Display(int width, int height, const char *title)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0)
    {
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

        m_window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,     SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
        m_context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_window);

        GLenum status = glewInit();
        if (status != GLEW_OK){
            std::cerr << "this is where the problem is" << std::endl;
        }
        m_isClosed = false;
    }
}


Display::~Display()
{
        std::cerr << "destructor ran" << std::endl;
        SDL_GL_DeleteContext(m_context);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(m_window);
        SDL_Quit();
}

void Display::Update()
{
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(m_window);

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            m_isClosed = true;
        }
    }
}

void Display::Clear(float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    glClearColor(r, g, b, a);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

bool Display::isClosed(){
    return m_isClosed;
}
```

**main.cpp**~

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Display.h"
#include "Shader.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Display display(800, 600, "test");
    Shader shader("basicshader");

    while (!display.isClosed())
    {
        display.Clear(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        shader.Bind();
        display.Update();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and here are the **errors** I'm recieving:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned int __cdecl Shader::CreateShader(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned int)" (?CreateShader@Shader@@SAIABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@I@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Shader::Shader(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0Shader@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)   C:\Users\Nas\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Open GL\Open GL\Shader.obj

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl Shader::LoadShader(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?LoadShader@Shader@@SA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV23@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Shader::Shader(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0Shader@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) C:\Users\Nas\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Open GL\Open GL\Shader.obj

error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Nas\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Open GL\Debug\Open GL.exe    1
```

Comment: You gave everything except the thing that's wrong. What command are you giving to link this?

Comment: I dont know what exactly it is that you're asking me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `Shader::` infront of the `CreateShader` implementation. In addition you have to remove the static keyword in the implementation:

```
         \/
GLuint Shader::CreateShader(const std::string& text, GLenum shadertype)
{
    ...
}
```

What you are defining right now is a local static method `::CreateShader` in global scope, that is completely unrelated to the member function `Shader::CreateShader`.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong here but I'm pretty sure when u define any class member as static there's no need for the "Shader::", if not then I must be doing something else wrong because I tried it and it didn't solve my problem, it just gave more errors :P.

Comment: Sorry, I oversaw something. I'll update my answer. Class member (static or not) always have to be implemented correctly. And the static keyword has to be only present in the declaration, not in the implementation. The way you do it now defines and implements a new static method in global scope that is completely unrelated to the member function.